# How to calculate matrix tr(AB)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have these Matrix A and B below in the image:

[image]

And i wonder how do i calculate the tr(AB)?
I have done this by taking the diagonal in each Matrix A and B:

3 * 6 + 1 * 5 + 5 * 9 = 67

But after that i get stuck i have tried to search for an answer but
i couldn't find any thing that explained that?

Comment: Well done on having remembered that $tr(M) = $ sum of diagonal elements, now you need to calculate $AB$ by multiplying the two matricies, and then take $tr$ace of the resulting matrix -- That said, it sounds like your main problem is knowing how to multiply them, this is something that can be easily looked up in wikipedia or textbooks introducing matricies.

Comment: Thanks so much!

Comment: Hi @Jonte YH, also, you don't have to find *every* entry of the product $AB$! The trick is that the $\left(i,i\right)$-entry of $AB$ is the dot product of the $i$th row of $A$ with the $i$th column of $B$. We then add these $\left(i,i\right)$ entries (there are three of them, one for each $1\leq i\leq 3$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read about the list of properties of trace of a matrix - [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_(linear_algebra)#Properties).

Now, in this problem, you have to find $AB$ first, but explicitly evaluating the matrix product and then sum the diagonal elements. There no other easier way about it.